# apply jittering to outliers data in a boxplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, jitter

do you have any idea of how to apply jittering just to the outliers data of a boxplot? This is the code:

```
ggplot(data = a, aes(x = "", y = a$V8)) +
geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0.5)+
geom_point(data=a, aes(x="", y=a$V8[54]), colour="red", size=3) + 
theme_bw()+
coord_flip()
```

thank you!!

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example?

Answer (score 17):

Added a vector to your data set to indicate which points are and are not outliers.  Then, Set the `geom_boxplot` to not plot any outliers and use a `geom_point` to plot the outliers explicity.

I will use the `diamonds` data set from `ggplot2` to illustrate.

***EDITED TO CORRECT THE OUTLIER DEFINITION***

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamonds2 <-
  diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  mutate(
         outlier_lwr = price < quantile(price, probs = 0.25) - IQR(price) * 1.5,
         outlier_upr = price > quantile(price, probs = 0.75) + IQR(price) * 1.5
         ) %>%
  ungroup

ggplot(diamonds2) +
  aes(x = cut, y = price) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +  # NO OUTLIERS
  geom_point(data = function(x) subset(x, outlier_lwr | outlier_upr), 
             position = 'jitter') # Outliers
```

[image]

Comment: I've never seen a function used in the `data = ` argument; that's brilliant!

Comment: the default for the outlier is a little off, so the points overlap the whiskers...use: `outlier.high = V8 > quantile(V8, .75) + 1.50*IQR(V8)` and `outlier.low = V8 < quantile(V8, .25) - 1.50*IQR(V8))`. Then can add `geom_jitter(data = filter(a, outlier.high ==T | outlier.low == T), color = "red", width = .2)`

Comment: To expand slightly on Matt L's comment (which is addressed in their answer): Peter's specification of an outlying value cut-off is slightly different from the Tukey convention. Tukey convention is upper/lower quartile +- 1.5*IQR but Peter uses median +- 1.5*IQR. Peter's answer also addresses only extremely high values and ignores extremely small values.

Answer (score 17):

This is slightly different approach than above (assigns a color variable with NA for non-outliers), and includes a correction for the upper and lower bounds calculations.

The default "outlier" definition is a point beyond the 25/75th quartile +/- 1.5 x the interquartile range (IQR).

Generate some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- data_frame(x= factor(rep(1:4, each  = 1000)),
                V8 = c(rnorm(1000, 25, 4), 
                       rnorm(1000, 50, 4),
                       rnorm(1000, 75, 4),
                       rnorm(1000, 100, 4)))
```

calculate the upper/lower limit outliers (uses dplyr/tidyverse functions):

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- a %>% group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(outlier.high = V8 > quantile(V8, .75) + 1.50*IQR(V8),
         outlier.low = V8 < quantile(V8, .25) - 1.50*IQR(V8))
```

Define a color for the upper/lower points:

```
a <- a %>% mutate(outlier.color = case_when(outlier.high ~ "red",
                                       outlier.low ~ "steelblue"))
```

*The unclassified cases will be coded as "NA" for color, and will not appear in the plot.*

The `dplyr::case_when()` function is not completely stable yet (may require github development version > 0.5 at [enter link description here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr)), so here is a base alternative if that does not work:

```
a$outlier.color <- NA
a$outlier.color[a$outlier.high] <- "red"
a$outlier.color[a$outlier.low] <- "steelblue"
```

Plot:

```
a %>% ggplot(aes(x, V8)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)  + 
  geom_jitter(color = a$outlier.color, width = .2) + # NA not plotted 
  theme_bw() + coord_flip()
```

[image]