# Disalign overplotted outliers in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector with a few important outliers, 5 altogether. Only 3 outlier values are distinct. The identical values therefore get overplotted in a geom_boxplot:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Ratio = c(rep(1,100), rep(0:1, 100), 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 7),
  ID = 1:305
)

df  %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Ratio)) +
  # boxplot:
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
  )
```

[image]

How can I make all 5 outlier values visible in the plot?

**EDIT**:

I think I'm getting closer with this but I have difficulty combining `df` and `outliers` and the resulting plot is not yet good as the outlier points should be aligned around the box's center line:

```
# define a vector with the outliers:
outliers <- boxplot.stats(df$Ratio)$out

df  %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Ratio)) +
  # boxplot:
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    # set outlier to NA:
    outlier.shape = NA
  )+
  # add jittered `outlier`:
  geom_jitter(data = tibble(outliers), aes(y = outliers, x = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Does `geom_jitter` not help?

Comment: does issue #4480 on the ggplot2 GitHub page help? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4480; or smilarly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141193/apply-jittering-to-outliers-data-in-a-boxplot-with-ggplot2

Comment: "outlier points should [b]e aligned around the box's center line": jittering is a random process (by default), so you will never get perfect symmetry or similar patterns.  You can control the horizontal dispersion with `width =` in `geom_jitter` as I did in my answer.  Automating the link between `geom_boxplot` and the filtering of the data for `geom_jitter` is computationally simple but potentially somewhat awkward.  Unfortunately I have other commitments that mean I cannot devote more time to the question right now.  Both links in @xx0020's comment are relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
df  %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Ratio, x=0)) +
  # boxplot:
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    outlier.alpha = 0 # To make default outliers invisible
  ) +
  geom_jitter(
    data = df %>% filter(Ratio > 2), # Adjust cutoff as desired
    width = 0.01, 
    height = 0
  )
```

giving

[image]

Comment: okay, that works for this example where the outliers are known...

Comment: Indeed.  But the formulae for calculating the location of the top of the box and the point beyond which outliers are plotted (by default, I believe it's 1.5 times the interquartile range above the top of the box) are known, so the correct cutoff can be calculated in the general case.

Comment: If we define the outliers like I did in the edited question: `outliers <- boxplot.stats(df$Ratio)$out`how would you proceed from there?

Answer (score 2):

There are some caveats this approach, but to align the outliers around the centre line one option is:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

df <- data.frame(
  Ratio = c(rep(1,100), rep(0:1, 100), 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 7),
  ID = 1:305
)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Ratio, x=0)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    outlier.alpha = 0
  ) +
  geom_quasirandom(
    color = ifelse(df$Ratio == boxplot.stats(df$Ratio)$out, "black", "transparent"),
    method = "smiley"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We could use `geom_jitter()` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Ratio)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0, color = "firebrick", alpha = 0.7, 
              size = 4.5) +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own answer, inspired partly by @Limey's approach but offering an automated solution to the issue of defining the outliers:

```
# define outliers:
outliers <- boxplot.stats(df$Ratio)$out

df  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 0, y = Ratio)) +
  # boxplot:
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.2,
    outlier.shape = NA
  )+
  # jittered outliers:
  geom_jitter(
    # filter `outliers  from `Ratio`:
    data = df %>% filter(Ratio %in% outliers), 
    width = 0.005, 
    color = "blue"
  )
```

[image]